# Что такое токен (token) и зачем его используют?

Tags: token, html, php

Раньше писал скрипты для автоматических действий на сайте. Обычно это отправка сообщений. Так вот, как правило, у всех были такие формы:

Пример:

- **to**: *12345*,
- **obj**: "*Bla bla bla*",
- **message**: "*Text text text...*",
- **token**: "*qHDdkw9234jJdkmskf23dmdksJDs2*"

Недавно в исходниках ВК тоже видел некий token...

Зачем нужен этот token? Чем он так полезен?

Comment: Традиционный ответ: зависит от контекста. Конкретно текущая строка - это явно случайно сгенерированное значение, связанное с пользователем и/или конкретным запросом. При сабмите формы этот токен проверится на валидность и совпадение с пользователем, и, если совпадения не произошло, форма не будет принята. Таким образом можно обеспечить, например, сроки отправки формы: записываем этот случайный токен в БД/кэш вместе со временем его генерации, если он приходит через какое-то время, которое больше запланированного - форма не принимается.

Comment: @Etki, зачем забивать БД мусором и вообще нагружать лишней фигнёй?  
Куки с флагом HTTPOnly или сессия вполне хорошо справляются с поставленной задачей.

Comment: @TheDoctor 

> зачем забивать БД мусором и вообще нагружать лишней фигнёй?

Это не мусор, ситуации бывают разные, а сессии любят блокировать чтение. Конечно, все что должно валяться в сессии все равно должно продолжать валяться в сессии, но БД может оказаться предпочтительней.

> Куки с флагом HTTPOnly

Угу, злоумышленник воткнет в куки и сам запрос одно и то же значение, и всё пройдет. Защита на пять.

Comment: Тык куки с этим флагом недоступны для редактирования, только если юзер сам залезет в настройки арбуза и там покопается.

Эмн... Можно переопределить пути сессий, настроить доступ к папке и сессии будут долго и хорошо служить на благо Чёрного Властелина :)

Лично мне больше сессии нравятся, для остального есть <strike>MasterCard</strike> локальное хранилище, куда я пихаю что только можно.

Comment: @TheDoctor, 

> Эмн... Можно переопределить пути сессий, настроить доступ к папке и сессии будут долго и хорошо служить на благо Чёрного Властелина :)

и как это поможет проблеме блокировки?

> Тык куки с этим флагом недоступны для редактирования, только если юзер сам залезет в настройки арбуза и там покопается.

Зачем тут юзер вообще? Атакующий скрипт состоит из десятка строчек.

Comment: @Etki, проблему блокировки каждый решает, как может, и как позволит ему его извращённая фантазия.  
Какой-то метод не работает у кого-то, зато отлично сработает у другого.

Юзер при том, что при флаге `HttpOnly` до такой куки добраться можно только через браузер, [**скриптам к ней доступа нет**.](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/HttpOnly)

Comment: @TheDoctor то есть я не могу в своем же скрипте проставить те куки, которые хочу? При том, что браузер вообще не участвует, а у меня на руках произвольный клиент или даже вообще прямое подключение по сокету? Печальбеда.

> Какой-то метод не работает у кого-то, зато отлично сработает у другого.

Мы точно сейчас про программирование?

Comment: @Etki, мне кажется спор ушёл куда-то не туда.  
Куки недоступны коду браузера, сервер их легко читает/изменяет, ибо браузер их так же отправляет с каждым запросом.  
А т.к. нам нужно защитить токен от хакера на клиенте, то флаг отлично отрабатывает свой хлеб :)

Про проблему блокировки я пока не думаю, куки же на повестке дня.

Comment: @Etki,
Таким образом можно обеспечить, например, сроки отправки формы: записываем этот случайный токен в БД/кэш вместе со временем его генерации, если он приходит через какое-то время, которое больше запланированного - форма не принимается.

А если например добавить в форму UNIXTime + Hash:

unix="1234567890"
hash="abcdef1234567890abcdef1234567890"

А в хеше что то типа: md5( $unix . "blablabla" );

Это ведь подойдет чтобы время формы чекнуть и чтобы юникс не подменили??

P.S. Как вы цитируете???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Основная цель - защита от [CSRF](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Межсайтовая_подделка_запроса).
Атакующий может оправить ядовитый запрос от лица жертвы, и целевая система будет думать, что запрос от авторизованного пользователя.
Одна из самых интересных атак, на мой вкус.
Пока единственная достаточно хорошая защита - это генерация некого ключа, которым подписывается каждая (в идеале, конечно) форма и ссылка. По этому ключу можно определить атаку и пресечь её.
Хотя и токены обходятся довольно легко в последнее время.

Answer (score 0):

Вообще это [CSRF](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%9C%D0%B5%D0%B6%D1%81%D0%B0%D0%B9%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D0%BA%D0%B0_%D0%B7%D0%B0%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D1%81%D0%B0)-защита.
Чтоб ты со своего сайта на настоящий не слал запросы.